# Learning: Xcode LIST_FOREACH in XCode. What is the use of LIST_FOREACH? if there is no such foreach concept in objectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, loops, syntax

While typing code in XCode i have found the word LIST_FOREACH. what is the purpose of LIST_FOREACH in XCode? why its displayed?

Since there is no other function such as foreach in XCode - Objective C,then what is the use of LIST_FOREACH?

Can anyone teach me what's the purpose of LIST_FOREACH in Objective-c?.When there is no foreach concept in Objective-c

Any answer is welcome :)

Comment: What do you mean by exact foreach(). What are you looking to achieve with that method?

Comment: There is no such method/function called foreach() in Objective-C.

Comment: "I need exact foreach()" - for what purpose?

Comment: learning.. i am studying

Comment: What are you studying that requires to know the syntax of non-existing function?

Comment: i have found foreach() while coding in xcode,, but i didnt found any syntax for it

Comment: for objective-c, there is no foreach(). You could use for-in instead

Answer (score 0):

**For your information there is no loop like foreach in objective or swift, like c# or other language.**

But the same can be achieved by the following code

```
NSArray *a = [NSArray new];       // Any container class can be substituted

for(id obj in a) {                // Note the dynamic typing (we do not need to know the
                                  // Type of object stored in 'a'.  In fact, there can be
                                  // many different types of object in the array.

    printf("%s\n", [[obj description] UTF8String]);  // Must use UTF8String with %s
    NSLog(@"%@", obj);                               // Leave as an object
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you attempting to do Fast Enumeration on arrays? You can do it as -

```
for (id tempObject in myArray) {
    NSLog(@"Single element: %@", tempObject);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Syntex of Fast Enumeration:

```
for (NSString* key in xyz) {
        id value = [xyz objectForKey:key];
        // do stuff
    }
```

For more info:

> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html